# How to read Config values in Cross Cutting project?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have followed DDD guidelines to structure my project, I have *Domain*, *Infrastructure*, *Application* and *Presentation* layers.

I have also defined a cross-cutting project called *Common*. All other projects have dependency on *Common*.

One of the things that I need in *Common* project is my config/setting values. I have defined all solution wide settings in a DB table. The *Common* project reads the settings and any other project can access these settings through *Common* project...

How should *Common* project access the DB? Anywhere else in the solution, I use *Infrastructure* layer to read from DB, but if I reference *Infrastructure* in *Common* project, I would get circular dependency.

Should *Common* project have it's own DB Reader? Or putting all the config in the *Common* project was not the correct design at the first place?

Comment: What kind of config/settings? Are these application related (e.g. caching, endpoints, connection strings, IoC, etc.) or demain related?

Comment: @plalx: thanks for your reply. These are solution wide config which are not sensitive and can be stored in plain text (so not connection string)... These are mainly config values that could change depending on which country the application is running in: for example Rent_Unit (could be per week or per month) Or the Name of the Country (e.g. New Zealand, UK, ...) also some Min and Max Limit for properties, for example Max Length for User Profile in characters... Also some end point that could be stored in Plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `common` package could be organized by feature. Here the `IConfigProvider` implementations would live in the same package as the interface.

E.g.

[image: common library]

You could also consider global configuration as a supporting BC and implement the appropriate anti-corruption layer in each downstream context, where every context has it's own view and interpretation of such configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I am not following, would you please explain the following questions... so ConfigProvider lives in Common project, so I assume it should have it's own DbReader to read the config value from DB? Could you please explain why domian.model is inside Common project? is `Entity` the structure we store the configuration values in?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini `domain.model` has nothing to do with your use case. I just wanted to show that `common` is a supporting library that can support many different layers. For instance, you could have a base `Entity` class in the `common.domain.model` from which entities in all other BCs inherit. In my above example, the `DbReader` would be an implementation of the `IConfigProvider` and yes it could live in the `common.config` package like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are always an interesting thing.

Since you haven't specified what languages/environments you are using and I have experience with C# I will use techniques and terminology related to strong typed OO languages like it.

Let's say that we will separate interface and implementation. I will use the c# notation that an interface begins with capital 'I' to make more clear what is an interface.

Your repositories are part of your domain. Lets say you have Account entity and you have AccountRepository for this entity.

What we will do is separate the interface for this repository from it's implementation. We will have IAccountRepository and a concrete implementation (maybe more than one, but this is very rare) for it: AccountRepository.

If we want to use SQL database we may have SQLAccountRepository. If we want to use MongoDB we may have MongoDBRepository. Both of these concrete repositories will implement the interface IAccountRepository.

IAccountRepository is part of your *Domain*, but the implementations (SQL, MongoDB etc.) are part of your *Infrastructure* layer as they will access external things (SQL server or MongoDB server in this example).

Your dependencies in this case will be '*Infrastructure* -> *Domain*' not '*Domain* -> *Infrastructure*'. This isolates your domain from the *Infrastructure* as the *Infrastructure* has reference to the *Domain* note vice versa.

By using interfaces your *Domain* only specifies ***what it needs*** not ***how it needs it***.

If you apply the same idea you can define interfaces in your *Common* project for getting (and setting if necessary) settings (ISettingsProvider, IApplicationSettings etc.) and allow the *Infrastructure* that references *Common* to provide implementation for these interfaces (SQLSettingsProvider etc.)

You can use dependency injection, service locator or similar technique to bind implementations to interfaces.

Comment: I would have thought that repositories are part of infrastructure... but either way, if I reference repositories from cross cutting project, I would get circular dependency.

Comment: Why would you reference repositories from Cross cutting project? If the repositories are part of your Domain they will only be referenced from Application and Infrastructure layer. The infrastructure will feference Cross cutting project and provider Implementation. Here is a diagram that shows how outher layers reference inner layers. https://shawnjlee.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/onion1.png.